# Ansible: Access host/group vars from within custom module

Tags: python, ansible

Is there a way how one can access host/group vars from within a [custom written module](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_modules.html)? I would like to avoid to pass all required vars as module parameters.

My module is written in Python and I use the boilerplate. I checked pretty much all available vars but they are not stored anywhere:

```
def main():
    pprint(dir())
    pprint(globals())
    pprint(locals())
    for name in vars().keys():
        print(name)
```

Now my only hope is they are somehow accessible through the undocumented module utils.

I guess it is not possible, since the module runs on the target machine and probably the facts/host/group vars are not transferred along with the module...

Edit: Found the [module utils](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/a5ac9aafada0eeb541b0d8dbc506b66cd38b504b/lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py) now and it doesn't look promising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your suggestion in [your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32103731/6577998), I did manage to read host_vars and local play vars through a custom [Action Plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#action-plugins).

I'm posting this answer for completeness sake and to give an explicit example of how one might go about this method, although you gave this idea originally :)

**Note** - this example is incomplete in terms of a fully functioning plugin. It just shows the how to access variables.

```py
from ansible.template import is_template
from ansible.plugins.action import ActionBase


class ActionModule(ActionBase):

    def run(self, tmp=None, task_vars=None):

        # some boilerplate ...
        
        # init
        result = super(ActionModule, self).run(tmp, task_vars)

        # more boilerplate ...

        # check the arguments passed to the task, where if missing, return None
        self._task.args.get('<TASK ARGUMENT NAME>', None)
        # or
        # check if the play has vars defined
        task_vars['vars']['<ARGUMENT NAME>']
        # or
        # check if the host vars has something defined
        task_vars['hostvars']['<HOST NAME FORM HOSTVARS>']['<ARGUMENT NAME>']

        # again boilerplate...

        # build arguments to pass to the module
        some_module_args = dict(
            arg1=arg1,
            arg2=arg2
        )

        # call the module with the above arguments...
```

In case you have your playbook variables with jinja 2 templates, you can resolve these templates in the plugin as follows:

```py
from ansible.template import is_template

# check if the variable is a template through 'is_template'
if is_template(var, self._templar.environment):
    # access the internal `_templar` object to resolve the template
    resolved_arg = self._templar.template(var_arg)
```

---

Some words of caution:

- 1. If you have a variable defined in your playbook as follows

```yaml
# things ...
#
      vars:
        - pkcs12_path: '{{ pkcs12_full_path }}'
        - pkcs12_pass: '{{ pkcs12_password }}'
```

The variable `pkcs12_path` **must not** match the host_vars name.

For instance, if you had `pkcs12_path: '{{ pkcs12_path }}'`, then resolving the template with the above code will cause a recursive exception... This might be obvious to some, but for me it was surprising that the host_vars variable and the playbook variable must **not** be with the same name.

- 2. You can also access variables through `task_vars['<ARG_NAME>']`, but I'm not sure where it's reading this from. Also it's less explicit than taking variables from `task_vars['vars']['<ARG_NAME>']` or from the hostvars.

---

*PS* - in the time of writing this, the example follows the basic structure of what Ansible consider an Action Plugin. In the future, the `run` method might change its signature...

Comment: Awesome, thanks for putting this together. I never went back to test my idea. Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 9):

> Is there a way how one can access host/group vars from within a custom
> written module?

Not built-in.

You will have to pass them yourself one way or the other:

- Module args.
- Serialize to local file system (with `pickle` or `yaml.dump()` or `json` or ...) and send the file over.
- any other innovative ideas you can come up with.

Unfortunately you can't just send over whole host/groupvar files as-it-is because you would have to implement the variable scope/precedence resolution algorithm of ansible which is undefined (it's not the [Zen philosophy of ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#ansible-variable-precedence) to define such petty things :P ).

--edit--

I see they have [some precedence defined](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) now.

> Ansible does apply variable precedence, and you might have a use for
> it. Here is the order of precedence from least to greatest (the last
> listed variables override all other variables):
>
> - command line values (for example, -u my_user, these are not variables)
> - role defaults (defined in role/defaults/main.yml) 1
> - inventory file or script group vars 2
> - inventory group_vars/all 3
> - playbook group_vars/all 3
> - inventory group_vars/* 3
> - playbook group_vars/* 3
> - inventory file or script host vars 2
> - inventory host_vars/* 3
> - playbook host_vars/* 3
> - host facts / cached set_facts 4
> - play vars
> - play vars_prompt
> - play vars_files
> - role vars (defined in role/vars/main.yml)
> - block vars (only for tasks in block)
> - task vars (only for the task)
> - include_vars
> - set_facts / registered vars
> - role (and include_role) params
> - include params
> - extra vars (for example, -e "user=my_user")(always win precedence)
>
> In general, Ansible gives precedence to variables that were defined
> more recently, more actively, and with more explicit scope. Variables
> in the defaults folder inside a role are easily overridden. Anything
> in the vars directory of the role overrides previous versions of that
> variable in the namespace. Host and/or inventory variables override
> role defaults, but explicit includes such as the vars directory or an
> include_vars task override inventory variables.
>
> Ansible merges different variables set in inventory so that more
> specific settings override more generic settings. For example,
> ansible_ssh_user specified as a group_var is overridden by
> ansible_user specified as a host_var. For details about the precedence
> of variables set in inventory, see How variables are merged.
>
> Footnotes
>
> 1 Tasks in each role see their own role’s defaults. Tasks defined
> outside of a role see the last role’s defaults.
>
> 2(1,2) Variables defined in inventory file or provided by dynamic
> inventory.
>
> 3(1,2,3,4,5,6) Includes vars added by ‘vars plugins’ as well as
> host_vars and group_vars which are added by the default vars plugin
> shipped with Ansible.
>
> 4 When created with set_facts’s cacheable option, variables have the
> high precedence in the play, but are the same as a host facts
> precedence when they come from the cache.

Answer (score 3):

I think you pretty much hit the nail on the head with your thinking here:

> I guess it is not possible, since the module runs on the target machine and probably the facts/host/group vars are not transferred along with the module...

However, having said that, if you really have a need for this then there might be a slightly messy way of doing it.  As of Ansible 1.8 you can set up [fact caching](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching), which uses redis to cache facts between runs of plays. Since redis is pretty easy to use and has [clients for most popular programming languages](http://redis.io/clients), you could have your module query the redis server for any facts you need. It's not exactly the cleanest way to do it, but it just might work.

Comment: That's very interesting! Right now it's not an option because it would require an additional redis host accessible from the local box and the remote box. That's a bit too much of overhead. But we might implement it that way later when we have more automation done with Ansible. Fact caching is something we probably want anyway later on. I'll accept your answer - while it is not the optimal solution it appears to be the best available.

Comment: You can simply install redis on the existing ansible server.  redis is very lightweight, so no additional server is required.

Comment: Well, this is a bit more complex here. Dealing with multiple thousand hosts in 8 colos with multiple separated vlans in each. We just getting started with Ansible. Right now this would involve too much effort but it's obvious we need fact caching not so far in the future and then this should get very easy to implement.