# Access playbook variables from custom module in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm writing a custom module in Ansible, specific to a Playbook. Is it possible to directly access a playbook variable, without needing to pass it to the task as a parameter?

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible, because the module is executed remotely and all the variables are not available unless explicitly passed.

I had the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026094/ansible-access-host-group-vars-from-within-custom-module) a while ago and Pruce P offered an interesting workaround in his answer.

Though I had another idea in the meantime, but this is only theoretical and never tested: Beside normal modules, Ansible has a special kind of module: *action plugins*. (...not documented) They are used exactly like modules but are executed locally. Since they run locally they do have access to Ansibles runner object which holds all the group/host vars etc.

The cool thing is, you can call a module programmatically from the action plugin. So you could have a small wrapper action plugin which then calls the actual module and passes all (required) vars to it. Since it is undocumented you need to look at the available plugins. For instance here is one which calls a module: [assemble](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/assemble.py#L136).

I have written something [here](https://gist.github.com/udondan/b730206056a018cf9838#file-include_vars_merged-py-L34) which interacts with vars from the runner object.