# Access Ansible facts from an Ansible module. Prefetch/Flush in Ansible?

Tags: module, ansible, ansible-facts

An Ansible module can produce custom facts by including them in its JSON output. Is it possible to access those facts from the same module when it is called next time during the same Ansible run? The idea is to use them to prefetch the is-state of a certain, er... class of things. Something that's called "resource type" in Puppet.

Or is there some other way of prefetching for Ansible modules?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do and why it doesn't work (show the output too)?

Comment: Example: several key-value pairs stored in a single file (say, user = password_hash). Adding/modifying a user/password is a candidate for one atomic task. In order to check for user existence, one has to read the same file multiple times.

I've got no "output", and I know how to implement it - the ugly way, at least. In this particular case the difference is negligible (just a couple of lines to parse), but with some other tasks this can potentially result in sub-optimal performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unless you implement it yourself. Modules do only have access to those vars which have been explicitly passed to the module. This is because the module is executed remotely while all facts are available in the runner on the client machine.

[I had a similar problem myself before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026094/ansible-access-host-group-vars-from-within-custom-module) Bruce P. suggested to use [fact caching](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching) and then query the redis cache from the module.

In your case it might be simpler though, since you want to have the value available if the module gets called a second time during the same run. You could simply store your data in a temporary file.

I had another idea to solve this but did not yet have the chance to test it: One could create an action plugin which works together with the module. An action plugin is like a module, but is executed locally, so has access to all facts. You can execute a module from within an action plugin and pass all the available facts. If I'm not mistaken `copy` is a good example for this. There is a [`copy` module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/cd9a7667aa39bbc1ccd606ebebaf3c62f228d601/files/copy.py) and a [`copy` action plugin](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py). The plugin then [calls the module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py#L97).

The easiest thing though would be to simply pass your facts to your module.

```
- your_module: your_fact={{ your_fact | default(False) }}
- your_module: your_fact={{ your_fact | default(False) }}
```

When first executed `your_fact` wouldn't exist, so you pass `False`. `your_module` then creates `your_fact` when first executed. So on the 2nd call it would exist and being passed in the 2nd task.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @udondan. I'm new to Ansible, so I've missed the plugins part. Will look into it. As for other suggestions, er... I thought of those myself, but the idea is to keep the execution logic out of playbooks as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the info on calling modules from within modules. Very useful