How to access Ansible facts in a custom module (e.g. ansible_all_ipv4_addresses)?
I am developing a Custom Ansible Module and need to access certain facts, such as ansible_all_ipv4_addresses, directly within the module code. However, I am unsure how to retrieve these facts without passing them explicitly from the playbook.
In SaltStack, for example, you can access system information via grains, but I couldn't find an equivalent way in Ansible Custom Modules. Here’s what I want to achieve:
I want to get the fact ansible_all_ipv4_addresses inside my Custom Module, without manually passing it as a parameter in the playbook.
Here is an example of what I am trying to do:
from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule

def run_module():
    module = AnsibleModule(
        argument_spec={},
        supports_check_mode=True
    )

    # How can I access ansible_all_ipv4_addresses here?
    ipv4_addresses = ???

    module.exit_json(changed=False, ipv4=ipv4_addresses)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_module()

Is there a way to directly access facts like ansible_all_ipv4_addresses inside the Custom Module, similar to how SaltStack handles grains? If not, what is the recommended approach for accessing these facts in Custom Modules?
Thanks in advance!

Not out-of-box but maybe via a Custom Action Plugin. See also Ansible: How to get all variables in own Custom Module? and How to access playbook variables from Custom Module in Ansible?

Some other answers you might want to study: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026094/ansible-access-host-group-vars-from-within-custom-module https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001668/access-ansible-facts-from-an-ansible-module-prefetch-flush-in-ansible

Regarding an equivalent to Salt grains you may have a look into How to ad-hoc filter hosts (target Managed Nodes) in Ansible using facts on CLI level?

I checked the source code of ansible and seem to have found a solution. By from ansible.module_utils.facts.compat import ansible_facts;
module_args=dict(filter=dict(type="str",required=False,default="all_ipv4_addresses"));
module=AnsibleModule(argument_spec=module_args,supports_check_mode=True);
facts = ansible_facts(module);
I can successfully get what I want. I don't know if this is standard or feasible, but it solves my problem.

@Tony, in this case you could answer your own question and also accept the answer later. At best with a small reproducible example of the solution you've find for your case.

@U880D,thanks for the reminder, I submitted an answer to my question, which contains a simple example

The following method solved my problem
#!/usr/bin/python

from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule
from ansible.module_utils.facts.compat import ansible_facts


def run_module():
    module_args = dict(filter=dict(type="str", required=False, default="all_ipv4_addresses"))
    module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec=module_args, supports_check_mode=True)
    ipv4_addresses = ansible_facts(module)

    module.exit_json(changed=False, ipv4=ipv4_addresses)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_module()

